# MultipleObjectsReturned error in django admin - but there is no duplication in database

Tags: mysql, sql, django

I'm having a problem in the Django admin. I'm using version 1.5.5

I have a Booth model which has a foreign key to my AreaLayout model, which then goes back through another few models with foreign and many2many keys. My model code can be seen on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/9fn0PR03). The initial indication of the problem in admin is that AreaLayouts are being duplicated in the select dropdown in Booth admin. The MultipleObjectsReturned error ([traceback](http://pastebin.com/qZw9ApM6)) is being raised when I then try to save a new booth. I was able to trace this back to the SQL query that django is creating to grab the AreaLayout list:

```
SELECT `venue_arealayout`.`id`, `venue_arealayout`.`name`, `venue_arealayout`.`description`, `venue_arealayout`.`area_id`, `venue_arealayout`.`additional_notes`
FROM `venue_arealayout`
INNER JOIN `venue_area` ON (`venue_arealayout`.`area_id` = `venue_area`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `venue_venue` ON (`venue_area`.`venue_id` = `venue_venue`.`id`)
INNER JOIN `venue_venue_venue_type` ON (`venue_venue`.`id` = `venue_venue_venue_type`.`venue_id`)
INNER JOIN `venue_venuetype` ON (`venue_venue_venue_type`.`venuetype_id` = `venue_venuetype`.`id`)
WHERE (`venue_arealayout`.`id` = 66 )
```

This query produces a duplicate in MySQL when I run it there.  Removing the final 2 JOINs results in a single result being returned (which is the desired result), whereas removing only the last join still results in duplication.

I tried running that query with `SELECT *` in place of selecting specific fields and the two results in that case are *almost* equal. The difference is that the venue in question has multiple venuetypes and I'm getting a result for each of those. Is there any way I can tell django not to include those joins for these queries, or is there a way I can get distinct results as far as AreaLayouts go?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're being caught by the bug reported in [ticket 11707](https://code.djangoproject.com/ticket/11707). One of the comments mentions that it can cause a `MultipleObjectsReturned` exception.

All I can suggest is that you stop using `limit_choices_to`. Your models are fairly complex, so I can't immediately see which one is causing the problem.

Comment: Thanks Alasdair, I think you're right. Looks like I need to come up with a workaround.